# Data management across segues

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, segue

This is a **concept** question.

Like many others, I have a parent scene and a child or detail scene.  When I click on a specific button in my parent scene, prepare to segue gets called and I pass over a couple of properties.  In my detail scene, I gather more information and need to save it for use by the parent.  I have seen various methods involving delegates, using singletons, and passing directly back to the parent properties.  Here is my question, would it be more correct to store the data in a database in the detail controller, or pass it back to the parent controller to store it?  It seems to me that since it was collected in the child, it should be stored there.

Would that be the *more correct* way of handling it?

Comment: I would suggest that neither store the data. Have the child pass back to the parent using a delegate and then use a data access layer to save it if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity, say the larger model is an array of custom objects and the detail view presents and edits one of those objects.  If you pass a custom object to the detail vc on before the segue, there's no need to "pass it back" later.  The parent vc passed that object in the first place, so we know it already has a pointer.

Instead, the parent vc should *notice* that the work has been done on the object it passed and react accordingly (usually update it's view) This can be done by one of a handful techniques:

1. just assume something changed and update the view on viewWillAppear
2. notice the custom object changed via KVO (observing one of its properties)
3. be notified that the object changed because the detail vc posts an NSNotification
4. learn that the object changed by arranging to be the delegate of the detail vc
5. pass the detail vc a block to execute when it updates the custom object

It's hard to say what's better without knowing more about your situation.  I can say that simple is usually better, and that favors (1).  I can also say that delegates are fine, but often overused.

Comment: Delegates are used most often for good reason. They introduce fewer dependencies than KVO or notifications. My personal favorite is passing in a block.

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with more than a few pieces of information, it would likely be much easier in the long run to use Core Data. If, down the road, you decided to add more functionality to the app, or wanted to store different kinds of information, it would take no more than a few extra lines of code to do this.

But from what it sounds like, you have a really simple app, so you should probably be fine just making an instance of your "parent scene" in your "detail scene" and storing whatever values you may have in the "detail scene" into properties that already exist in the "parent scene".

Does that answer your question well enough?

Comment: "Making an instance of your parent scene" is probably not what you meant, right?  That would be a mistake for sure.

Comment: Right now, it is a simple application that I'm working on.  The detail screen is just a picture and a text block.  But it's just a learning tool toward more robust applications that might be dealing with inventory or item properties (temperature ranges for storage, description, contents, pricing flags, etc).  If I was doing this in a windows or linux environment, I would do the updates on the screen where I entered the data, since it can do all the field edits and respond directly to any error conditions directly, but IOS and MVC throw some different options in the mix so I'm asking.